Transform sequence into ragged list
I want to transform
seq = {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y};

into
{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67}

The only way I found is rather ugly and needs Quiet
str = StringJoin @ ReplaceAll[{x :> "{", y -> "}", n_?NumberQ :> "," <> ToString[n] <> ","}] @ seq


"{,1,,2,{,3,{,4,,5,}},67,}"

res = DeleteCases[Quiet @ ToExpression @ str, Null, -1]


{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67}

Is there a more elegant way to get res?

Something like this, maybe
FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{x, sub : Except[x | y] .., y} :> {sub}], seq]
(* {{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67}} *)

This has an extra level compared to your desired outcome, but I think you need to be careful with your semantics. If your seq wasn't a special case of having x and y as first and last elements, then you wouldn't want to flatten, would you? Also, shouldn't you be able to distinguish {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y} from {1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67}? So, I posit that the above is actually a more correct output. But you can certainly remove a layer if you really want to
Flatten[FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{x, sub : Except[x | y] .., y} :> {sub}], seq], 1]


Function "destructuring" approach, going from the inside out:
Clear@linkXY
linkXY[lst_List /; FreeQ[lst, x | y]] := lst
linkXY[{a___, x, Shortest[b___], y, c___}] := linkXY[{a, {b}, c}]

seq = {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y};
linkXY[seq]
(* {{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67}} *)

This will also work if there are any empty sets, i.e., places where x,y appear consecutively.

Here's another solution, along the lines of the OP.  I can imagine that this might not be totally robust, due to the careful way we have to replace "x," and ", y": this has to take into account that ToString always places a space after each comma in a List, and I could see that implementation changing behind the scenes without documentation. Without more test cases, it's hard to tell.  In any case, it works on the test case in the OP, though:
seq = {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y};
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@seq, {"x, y" :> "{}", "x," -> "{", ", y" -> "}"}]
(* {{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67}} *)


Lets process this using Fold. We will replace each number with a list consisting of the number, and its depth:
g[{level_, current_List}, element_Integer] := {level, Append[current, {element, level}]}
g[{level_, current_List}, x] := {level + 1, current}
g[{level_, current_List}, y] := {level - 1, current}

r = Last@Fold[g, {0, {}}, {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y}]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {67, 1}} *)

For this example, the maximum depth is 3:
maxLevel = Max[Last /@ r]

(* 3 *)


In the following code I make use Framed as an auxiliary head. You could use a different inert one as well (but not List):
NestWhile[
    {SequenceReplace[#[[1]], h:{({_, #[[2]]} | _Framed) ..} :> Framed[First/@h]], #[[2]]-1 } &,
    {r, maxLevel},
    Last[#] > 0 &]


Now just extract the result from there:
%[[1,1,1]]
(* {1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67} *)


seq = {x, 1, 2, x, 3, x, 4, 5, y, y, 67, y};

Catenate@(Rest /@ Reverse@FixedPoint[
  SequenceReplace[#, {{x_, a__}, {x_, b__}} :> {x, b, {a}}] &, 
  Reverse@SequenceCases[seq, {x_Symbol, a__?NumericQ} :> {x, a}]])
(* {1, 2, {3, {4, 5}}, 67} *)

